# Newbie: the meaning of some SQL statements

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using **MySQL**, I have a **dump** file, the content of it are something like following

```
TRUNCATE TABLE cars;

ALTER TABLE cars DISABLE KEYS;

INSERT INTO cars ...    ;

ALTER TABLE cars ENABLE KEYS;

OPTIMIZE TABLE cars
```

I am wondering what are the following statements(from the above dump) doing respectively:

**1.**

```
ALTER TABLE cars DISABLE KEYS;
```

**2.**

```
ALTER TABLE cars ENABLE KEYS;
```

**3.**

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE cars
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DISABLE KEYS` tells mySQL not to update indexes while you are inserting.  `ENABLE KEYS` tells it to recreate and then begin updating indexes again.  Lastly [OPTIMIZE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html) does a number of things including updating statistics and sorting index pages.  This is important after large inserts/updates/deletes.

The code above would typically be used for a bulk insert/update.  Disabling indexes helps the performance of large insert/update/delete operations.

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS` tells MySQL to stop updating nonunique indexes.

`ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS` then should be used to re-create missing indexes.

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` should be used if you have deleted a large part of a table or if you have made many changes to a table with variable-length rows (tables that have VARCHAR, VARBINARY, BLOB, or TEXT columns).

Did you bother searching google?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 0):

This feature can be activated explicitly for a MyISAM table. ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS tells MySQL to stop updating nonunique indexes. ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS then should be used to re-create missing indexes. MySQL does this with a special algorithm that is much faster than inserting keys one by one, so disabling keys before performing bulk insert operations should give a considerable speedup. Using ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS requires the INDEX privilege in addition to the privileges mentioned earlier.

[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) is the source